# Update Not working properly in Netezza. This is actually a general topic

Tags: sql, sql-update, netezza

I don't why update query is not behaving properly or I am missing something very trivial here?
Here is the sequence of very simple steps I am running.

**Step 1:  Creating table**

```
CREATE table SNAPDATE_YOS as SELECT SNAPSHOTDATE, PREFERENCE_ID, CVALIDEMAIL, (CVALIDEMAIL * 1.0125) AS new_CVALIDEMAIL
FROM RPT_EMAIL_CATEGORY_PREFERENCE 
WHERE SNAPSHOTDATE = '2014-07-07 00:00:00'
AND PREFERENCE_ID = 'Yosemite';
```

1 rows affected

```
Select * from SNAPDATE_YOS;
```

> SNAPSHOTDATE || PREFERENCE_ID || CVALIDEMAIL || NEW_CVALIDEMAIL
>
> 2014-07-07 00:00:00|| Yosemite || 97676 ||  98896.9500

**Step 2: Updating table RPT_EMAIL_CATEGORY_PREFERENCE for a join condition with created table in step 1.**

```
UPDATE RPT_EMAIL_CATEGORY_PREFERENCE
SET CVALIDEMAIL = ROUND(S.new_CVALIDEMAIL,0)
FROM SNAPDATE_YOS S
JOIN RPT_EMAIL_CATEGORY_PREFERENCE P ON P.PREFERENCE_ID = S.PREFERENCE_ID 
WHERE P.SNAPSHOTDATE = '2014-11-21 00:00:00'
AND P.PREFERENCE_ID = 'Yosemite';
```

34 rows updated.

In my opinion only one row should be updated as join condition is giving me only one row.

Here are the supporting statements for it.

**Supporting statement 1 : Selecting rows on the condition.**

```
Select ROUND(S.new_CVALIDEMAIL,0) as CVALIDEMAIL
FROM SNAPDATE_YOS S   
JOIN RPT_EMAIL_CATEGORY_PREFERENCE P ON P.PREFERENCE_ID = S.PREFERENCE_ID 
WHERE P.SNAPSHOTDATE = '2014-11-21 00:00:00'
AND P.PREFERENCE_ID = 'Yosemite';
```

Output:

> CVALIDEMAIL
>
> 98897

**Supporting Statement 2: Selecting all columns**

```
Select *
FROM SNAPDATE_YOS S   
JOIN RPT_EMAIL_CATEGORY_PREFERENCE P ON P.PREFERENCE_ID = S.PREFERENCE_ID 
WHERE P.SNAPSHOTDATE = '2014-11-21 00:00:00'
AND P.PREFERENCE_ID = 'Yosemite';
```

1 row selected

**Supporting Statement 3: Selecting data from the table which needs to be updated.**

```
Select * from RPT_EMAIL_CATEGORY_PREFERENCE;
```

34 rows selected.

In my opinion only 1 row should be updated from RPT_EMAIL_CATEGORY_PREFERENCE table which satisfies the update condition. Am I missing something very trivial here?

> Query Plan:
>
> QUERY PLANTEXT:
>
> Nested Loop (cost=1.6..1.7 rows=34 width=113 conf=51)
>
> l: Sequential Scan table "RPT_EMAIL_CATEGORY_PREFERENCE" (cost=0.0..0.0 rows=34 width=105 conf=100)
>
> r: Materialize (cost=0.0..0.0 rows=1 width=16 conf=0)
>
> ```
>   l: Hash Join (cost=0.0..0.0 rows=1 width=16 conf=51)
>
>      l: Sequential Scan table "S" (cost=0.0..0.0 rows=1 width=266 conf=80)
>
>      r: Hash (cost=0.0..0.0 rows=1 width=15 conf=0)
>
>          l: Sequential Scan table "P" (cost=0.0..0.0 rows=1 width=15 conf=64)
> ```

**NZ Version**

> [nz@usga-qts-tfam-01 ~]$ nzrev
>
> Release 7.1.0.2-P2 [Build 39804]

Thanks in advance.
Vivek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you are joining to RPT_EMAIL_CATEGORY_PREFERENCE twice.  You may not realize it because the join with the table specified to update is implicit.

```
UPDATE RPT_EMAIL_CATEGORY_PREFERENCE  
--  ^ First reference to RPT_EMAIL_CATEGORY_PREFERENCE (with no alias)
SET CVALIDEMAIL = ROUND(S.new_CVALIDEMAIL,0)
FROM SNAPDATE_YOS S 
-- Which is then joined to SNAPDATE S with NO join criteria, making it a cross join producing
-- 1 x 34 rows
JOIN RPT_EMAIL_CATEGORY_PREFERENCE P ON P.PREFERENCE_ID = S.PREFERENCE_ID 
-- The third join then joins 1 row from RPT_EMAIL_CATEGORY_PREFERENCE with no join criteria
-- other than a WHERE clause which makes the output to 1 x 34 x 1 rows.
-- This is because the RPT_EMAIL_CATEGORY_PREFERENCE when referenced with a different alias
-- is treated as a separate table.
WHERE P.SNAPSHOTDATE = '2014-11-21 00:00:00'
AND P.PREFERENCE_ID = 'Yosemite';
```

The UPDATE I think you want is:

```
UPDATE RPT_EMAIL_CATEGORY_PREFERENCE 
SET CVALIDEMAIL = ROUND(SNAPDATE_YOS.new_CVALIDEMAIL,0)
FROM SNAPDATE_YOS
WHERE 
RPT_EMAIL_CATEGORY_PREFERENCE.PREFERENCE_ID = SNAPDATE_YOS.PREFERENCE_ID 
AND RPT_EMAIL_CATEGORY_PREFERENCE.SNAPSHOTDATE = '2014-11-21 00:00:00'
AND PRPT_EMAIL_CATEGORY_PREFERENCE.PREFERENCE_ID = 'Yosemite';
```

I removed the aliases for clarity (opinions may vary as to whether that's helpful or not in this case). You should only reference the table being UPDATEd once.  For Netezza, inner joins in an UPDATE are implicitly specified by the FROM and WHERE clauses.

Comment: Yes Scott, it was exactly what I noticed later. Thanks a lot.